# how to pass "this" in c++

Tags: c++

I'm confused with the `this` keyword in C++, I'm not sure that if I'm doing the right thing by passing `this`. Here is the piece of code that I'm struggling with:

```
ClassA::ClassA( ClassB &b) {

    b.doSth(this);
    // trying to call b's routine by passing a pointer to itself, should I use "this"?
}

ClassB::doSth(ClassA * a) {
       //do sth
}
```

Comment: when you "itself" in that comment, do you mean the ClassA object, or the ClassB object?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: do you have a question, or were you just sharing?

Comment: He's asking for clarification on his code.

Answer (score 32):

You're using it correctly.  The this pointer points to the current object instance.

```
class helper 
{
public:
     void help(worker *pWorker) {
          //TODO do something with pWorker . . .
     }

     void help2(worker& rWorker) {
          //TODO do something with rWorker . . .
     }
};

class worker 
{
public:
     void dowork() {
          //this one takes a worker pointer so we can use the this pointer.
          helper.help(this);

          //to pass by reference, you need to dereference the this pointer.
          helper.help2(*this);
     }
     helper helper;
};
```

Also, say you declare `worker *pW = new worker()`.  If you call one of the methods (dowork) on the `pW` object, you will notice that the `this` pointer and pW have the exact same value (they are both the same address).

(haven't tested that to make sure it builds, but I think it should).

Comment: No it doesn't compile because the class 'helper' has the class 'worker' inside whereas it's only declared after.

Answer (score 13):

In C++, `this` is a keyword which is defined as "the pointer to the current object instance".  So your code above is correct.

Depending on the inheritance/composition relationship between `ClassA` and `ClassB`, there are probably better ways to achieve what you are doing than by using the `this` pointer.

Answer (score 6):

It's perfectly OK to pass 'this' or '*this' as you are doing.

**Lifetime Dangers:**

One point about the example you've supplied is that you're calling `doSth` from the constructor of `ClassA`.  The object that's passed to `doSth` is possibly a partially constructed object:

```
class ClassC {
public:
  ClassC ()
  : m_c ()
  {}
  int m_c;
};

class ClassA : public ClassC {
public:
  ClassA (ClassB & b)
  : ClassC ()
  , m_b ( b.doSth (this) )  // ClassC constructed
                            // ClassA members partially init.
  {
    b.doSth (this);         // ClassA members initialized
  }

  // ...
  int m_a;
};

class ClassD : public ClassA {
public:
  ClassD(ClassB & b)
  : ClassA (b)              // Partially init
  , m_d ()
  {
                            // ClassC and ClassA constructed
                            // ClassD members initialized
  }
  int m_d;
};
```

There may be problems if `doSth` uses members that have not yet been initialized:

```
void ClassB::doSth (ClassA * a) {
  int i = a->m_c;     // OK m_c is initialized

  int j = a->m_a;     // Not OK, m_a not initialized when called
                      // from member initialization list.

  int k = static_cast<ClassD*> (a).m_d;  // Not OK
}
```

**Using the dynamic type of the object:**

Finally, any use of the dynamic type of the object (eg. virtual calls, dynamic_cast, typeid) will have different results on a partially constructed object than on a complete object (and in some case you can have undefined behaviour).

```
void ClassB::doSth (ClassA * a) {
  if (ClassD * d = dynamic_cast<ClassD *> (a))
  {
    // Never true when called from ClassA::ClassA
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case using `this` will pass a pointer to the caller class, which is A, to b.DoSth. It seems that you are doing it right. `this` keyword always points to the class instance that you are using it from.

Answer (score 0):

`this`  is a pointer to the object instance, so what you are doing is correct.

Read [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180225084650/http://www.codersource.net/2010/02/11/c-tutorial-this-pointer/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a const pointer to its own object. `this` pointer is nonmodifiable.

```
  ClassA::ClassA( ClassB &b) {

        b.doSth(this);
        // here 'this' refers to this object ie the instance of ClassA. 
        // When you pass 'this' to doSth function --> is equivalent to passing 
        // the instance of current object of ClassA.
        //   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to make it the **this** as in **thiscall**, or, **the actual very first parameter** of any **member functions** (for g++), there is only one way: by the **member access operators**:

```
A* a = sth_that_give_you_an_A();
((B*)a)->doSth();
```

or in your case, if you want to pass the instance of class `A` to `B::doSth`.

```
((B*)this)->doSth();
```

Or, you may want to cast it to `void*` first to make your compiler happy.
If this is what you actually want, it is somehow the only way to do that.

**However, an instance of class `A` may not also be an instance of class `B`**. It is very rare that you want actually do this. You should find a proper way that allow you to down cast an instance of `A` to its subclass `B` with confidence.

Or otherwise, if you want to call `B::doSth` on the instance of `B`, it is just as normal as what you may do.